# Programatically identifying a "sequence" in a list of numbers

Tags: math, coldfusion, sequences

I need to identify *if* a list of numbers is in true sequence. Specifically a sequence of 5.

**Example 1:**

- (original series)    `1,3,4,67,43,20`
- (ordered series)     `1,3,4,20,43,67`
- Is it a sequence of 5?    `FALSE`

**Example 2**

- (original series)    `147,10,143,432,144,23,145,146`
- (ordered series)     `10,23,143,144,145,146,147,432`
- Is it a sequence of 5?  `TRUE`  (ie 143-147)

Currently - I loop over the ordered list, and check if the current number is equal to the last number +1, and keep a counter. This works, but I'm curious if there is a BETTER way to do this mathematically, or programatically.

```
<cfscript>
_list1 = [1,3,4,67,43,20]; // should evaluate to FALSE
_list2 = [147,10,143,432,144,23,145,146]; // should evaluate to TRUE

_list = _list2; // switch list in one place - test purposes only.
_seq = 1; // sequence counter
_cap = ''; // value of the upper most number of the sequence
_msg = 'There is not a consecutive sequence of 5.'; // message to user

// sort the array smallest to largest 
arraySort( _list, 'numeric' ); 

// loop the array - compare the last number with the current number 
for ( i=2; i LTE arrayLen( _list ); i++ ) {
    _last = _list[i-1]; // the LAST number - we started at the second element, so we shouldn't error.
    _this = _list[i]; // this current number
    // compare the two numbers
    if ( val( _this ) EQ val( _last ) + 1 ) {
        _seq = _seq + 1; // increment our sequence
        _cap = _this; // set the top number
    }
}

// re-set the message if we meet some threshold (5) is hardcoded here 
if ( val( _seq ) GTE 5 ) {
    _msg = 'Sequence of ' & _seq & ' to ' & _cap;
}

// write the message 
writeoutput( _msg );    
</cfscript>
```

Comment: What's the real world use case for this? Or just a bit of fun with maths?

Comment: +1 to duncan's answer below. modify your for loop to only run if arraylen(_list) gte 5. also, reset _seq back to 1 when the sequence breaks (i.e. if 2-4 numbers are in sequence and the list is longer than 5. ALSO some other things to consider: what if your list contains multiple sequences? which of them should be used? first? last? longest? this may require further code changes.

Comment: @mike - the "real world" example is in sports analysis, I've got a bunch of data and I want to know when a person repeated some statistic x time consecutively... sometime I'll be looking for 3-peats or 5-peats it depends on what I'm after but I'm only interested if they happen back-to-back... It's not that the loop doesn't work - I'm just concerned about the user base doing a lot of searches, and the possible bogging down. in most cases, it's a small range searches LOTS of times, so it's prob not an issue... however I like to learn better ways of thinking, my math background is weak so...

Comment: Are all of the numbers in your list greater than 1? Also, are there any duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

For performance, I would say wrap your loop in an IF statement that first checks there are at least 5 elements; no point looping over 4 elements.

And then I'd say, do a check within the loop if 'seq' = 5, and break out of the loop immediately (unless you actually need to find out the length of the sequence if it's greater than 5).

Another thing you might consider trying. Before your loop, you could compare the first element of the list and the last element of the list.  If the difference between them is less than 5, then there's no point doing the loop at all.  Although from your data it looks like this might not be a probable occurance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want to learn more about is algorithmic time complexity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

Your current algorithm first does a sort then iterates over all of the elements. To determine the time complexity of your algorithm, we first have to know what the time complexity of Coldfusion's sorting algorithm. Since Coldfusion delegates to Java, and [Java Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) use a QuickSort algorithm, we know that the sorting portion of your algorithm takes `n*log(n)` time. The second part of your algorithm, which iterates over the array, takes `n` time. Adding these two time complexities together, we get `n+(n*log(n))`.

When analyzing the time complexity of your algorithm, we are only concerned with the slowest part: `n*log(n)`. So, the Big O time complexity is `O(n*log(n))`.

What does this mean? The sorting portion of your solution is the worst part. If you can solve the problem without sorting, you'd improve the speed of your application-- assuming your new solution doesn't do anything that takes more time than sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an Array out of the sequence and then compare the Array. Here is a good example: [link](http://milanchandnacf.blogspot.com/2012/02/equate-arrays-structs-query-or-possible.html)

Comment: I think you missed my point - I'm looking for the most efficient way to determine IF there is an actual sequence - once i determine that I can do whatever I want - but it's the function of determining the condition that I'm looking for. But thank you for the link.

Comment: I thought you were trying to evaluate whether a sequence of numbers matched a desired sequence of numbers. I think I get what your saying then. You're looking for a sequence numbers which are  incremented by 1, that are within a larger sequence of numbers and you want to know the length of the subsequence, correct?

Comment: yes - 1) IF it exists, 2) how long, and 3) what's the 'top' number

Comment: I can't think of a significantly more efficient way of doing it, nor could I find anything. What is the need to make it more efficient? If there is a significant performance issue you are facing? Perhaps we could attack the problem from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this answer here because I needed a function to output a series of numbers with any interior series of more than 2 in sequence as hyphenated (i.e. `1,3,4,5,7` as `1,3-5,7`) and didn't find it anywhere else quickly. Your code looks like it's no longer than mine so mine may do you no favor, although it sort of answers your question in that the active `cfreturn` gives longest sequence (which you may compare with your floor of 5. (My commented out `cfreturn` gives my needed abbreviation of interior sequences):

```
<cffunction name="fNumSeries" output="1" hint="pass in sorted array, get count of longest sequence">
<cfargument name="raNums" required="1" type="array">
<cfset numHold=raNums[1]>
<cfset isSeq="">
<cfset hasSeq=0>
<cfsavecontent variable="numSeries">
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(raNums)#" index="idxItem">
    <cfif idxItem eq 1>#raNums[1]#<!--- always output the first --->
    <cfelse>
        <!--- if in a sequence and not the last array element, no output --->
        <cfif numHold+1 eq raNums[idxItem] and idxItem neq arraylen(raNums)>
            <!--- capture the first value of the sequence --->
            <cfif len(isSeq) eq 0><cfset isSeq=numHold></cfif>
        <cfelseif len(isSeq)><!--- was in sequence but no longer --->
            <!--- if more than 2 in a row, show as sequence (n-n) --->
            <cfif idxItem eq arraylen(raNums) and raNums[idxItem] gt isSeq+1>
                - #raNums[idxItem]#
                <cfif hasSeq lt numHold - isSeq+1><cfset hasSeq=numHold - isSeq+1></cfif>
            <cfelseif raNums[idxItem] gt isSeq+3>
                - #numHold#, #raNums[idxItem]#
                <cfif hasSeq lt numHold - isSeq+1><cfset hasSeq=numHold - isSeq+1></cfif>
            <!--- otherwise show the 2nd (held) sequential value and current array value --->
            <cfelse>, #isSeq+1#, #raNums[idxItem]#
            </cfif>
            <cfset isSeq="">
        <cfelse>, #raNums[idxItem]#<!--- not in sequence --->
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
    <cfset numHold=raNums[idxItem]>
</cfloop>
</cfsavecontent>
<!--- <cfreturn replace(numSeries, " ,", ",", "all")> --->
<cfreturn hasSeq>
</cffunction>
```